# Google Recaptcha v3 in vue.js

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, recaptcha, recaptcha-v3

I'm trying to secure a register form that is built in vue.js with google recaptcha v3.
I'm using the npm package vue recaptcha v3 (https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-recaptcha-v3).

This is where I have integrated the vue recaptcha v3 on my site (around the register button).

```
<vue-recaptcha sitekey="mysitekey" :loadRecaptchaScript="true">
        <b-button type="submit" variant="primary" class="min-w-50 mt-2" :disabled="disableForm">Register now</b-button>
</vue-recaptcha>
```

and I have imported the VueRecaptcha from 'vue-recaptcha' and registered it in the components.

When opening the website, I see the "protected by google recaptcha" badge on the bottom left.

The problem is, that when I try to send the form manually by myself, I can't submit it even though I'm not a bot :-)

When I click the register button, it sends another post request to https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/reload?k=mysitekey

Do I have to do anything more so that it only recognizes bots as bots and not me?

Thanks in advance